# Invoke-Web request with proxy PowerShell

Tags: html, powershell, proxy

There is a script:

```
$html = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://www.mcafee.com/enterprise/en-us/downloads/security-updates.html
$dathtml = ($html.parsedhtml.getelementsbytagname("TR") |% { ( $_.children | ?{ $_.tagName -eq "td"} | % innerText ) } | Select-Object -First 1).Split('xdat')[0] 
Write-Host $dathtml
```

The problem is the following:

```
Invoke-WebRequest : ERROR
Cache Access Denied.
The following error was encountered while trying to retrieve the URL: https://www.mcafee.com/*
Cache Access Denied.
Sorry, you are not currently allowed to request https://www.mcafee.com/* from this cache until you have authenticated yourself.
Please contact the cache administrator if you have difficulties authenticating yourself.
Generated Wed, 25 Jul 2018 09:49:32 GMT by xxxxx (xxxx)
At line:1 char:9
+ $html = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://www.mcafee.com/enterprise/en-u ...
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-WebRequest], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:2 char:1
+ $dathtml = ($html.parsedhtml.getelementsbytagname("TR") |% { ( $_.chi ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

Is there any way to integrate the proxy server authentication method into the script ( AD auth ). If I run this script on my computer ( without proxy, on public net etc... ) it works. But I have to run this script from another computer which use proxy, the site is allowed but not able to get the information what I need. Any suggestion?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Invoke-WebRequest` has a `-ProxyCredential` argument.

Use a credentials object there. (username should be in the form "Domain\name")

You can do:

```
$cred = Get-Credential -Message 'Please enter your credentials for the proxy server.'
if ($cred) { 
    $url  = "https://www.mcafee.com/enterprise/en-us/downloads/security-updates.html"
    $html = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -ProxyCredential $cred
    # the rest of your code goes here
}
```

I cannot help you with the actual McAfee commands needed. For that you should search the McAfee communities and it will depend on the product you want to update.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but how and where can I use this? How it will be look like in my script?  I'm a beginner in this :/ Thank you for Your Help!

Comment: Thanks for the help. With this and a little google search it's working fine :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also add authentication headers to the web request, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42683385/powershell-v5-invoke-webrequest-adding-2-headers-authorization-header-and-accept/50135987#50135987)